# Open documents with office 365 in SharePoint Online

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, display-templates

I have a display template called "Item four lines" based on the out of the box "Item two lines" template which I modified to shown 4 lines rather than 2.

My documents are coming up correctly to match my search query, however when I click on the documents returned by the search results instead of these opening in the browser (Word Online, Excel Online, PowerPoint Online, etc) I get propmpted to save the documents locally. The ideal behaviour here will need to be the same as clicking on a document from a document library where the documents are opened automatically by Word Online, Excel Online, PowerPoint Online, etc in the broweser.

Is there anything that I need to add or do to the display template to achieve this?

Any help will be greatly appreactiated